# Reduce margin between vector with overleftarrow and index

Tags: positioning, subscripts, vector

I usually write vectors using `\boldsymbol`. Sometimes, I have to add an arrow using `\overleftarrow`. For these vectors, there's a large margin between the vector and its index. This is not the case for vectors without the arrow.

I can fix it by manually adding a `\hspace{-2pt}` to the index, but I'd rather not have to do this every time.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    Wrong: $\overleftarrow{\boldsymbol{h}}_{j+1}$ \\
    Workaround: $\overleftarrow{\boldsymbol{h}}_{\hspace{-2pt}j+1}$ \\
    Correct: $\boldsymbol{h}_{j+1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I globally reduce the margin between the vector and the index?

Comment: Are you really using arrows point to the left as arrows for vectors? Also `\boldsymbol`?

Comment: I would stick with `$\overleftarrow{\boldsymbol{h}}\!_{j+1}$`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer use bold to mark vectors. The arrow to the left is not because it's a vector, it indicates what information is stored inside.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's very good. I'd prefer a global setting, but if there is no such thing, `\!` is much easier to type and remember than some negative horizontal space

Comment: For your global solution, do you want the negative space only if the vector carries an index, or always? In the second case, the solution is trivial (just introduce `\newcommand{\OverLeftarrow}[1]{\overleftarrow{#1}\!})`, and in in the first case I'm wondering if this will be worth the effort.

Comment: @marmot If there is no index and I add the negative space, the vector might be too close to following symbols. So I only want to have it for vectors that actually have an index.

Comment: Well, in that case you want a macro that checks if what comes after is an index. Do you really think this is worth the effort?

Comment: I was just adding this answer:   `\makeatletter
    \let\oldoverleftarrow\overleftarrow
    \renewcommand{\overleftarrow}[1]{\oldoverleftarrow{#1}\@ifnextchar_{\!}{}}
    \makeatother`

Comment: @koleygr I get the error message `Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \@ifnextchar. \end{frame}` for `\frac{\overleftarrow{\boldsymbol{h}}}{j}` (I don't usually compute fractions with vectors, but it's a simple MWE where the macro fails). But something like that could work.
However, @marmot is probably right and it's not worth the effort. Using `\!` is already a good simplification, I didn't know about it.

Comment: `\newcommand\OLAss[1]{\overleftarrow{\boldsymbol{#1}}\!}`, with usage `\OLAss{h}_{j+1}`

Comment: I was ready to tell you something similar (that my command works but with bad result... This is when last character of the string inside the "arrow command" is a digit... Then the original code is better and the negative space causes problem)... But this gave me the idea to add a phantom digit (of no width) at the end of the parameter that would globbaly fix  this problem (and could be added to the original code as a fix)